# Strange canvas color bug in the default browser on Android 4.1.2

Tags: javascript, android, browser, html5-canvas

I have run into a very strange bug in the default internet browser on Android 4.1.2 (Samsung GT-N8010 Tablet).

I have reduced the production code into a simple [jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lnd3v/)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnd3v/) which manages to reproduce the bug.

**Case 1** creates a red and transparent checkerboard canvas and draws it on a blue canvas to produce a blue and red checkerboard. The canvas sizes are 400x200. Works as expected.

**Case 2** creates a black and white checkerboard canvas and then through per pixel manipulation changes them to transparent and red, and finally draws the now red and transparent canvas on a blue canvas. Same canvas sizes as in the first case. Produces the same end result as the first case.

**Case 3** is *exactly* the same as Case 2 except for the canvas sizes which are now 400x350. **The blue has now magically turned magenta!**

The javascript function responsible for converting the black & white canvas to transparent and a color (red in this test) looks like this:

```
var convertGreyscaleToTintedTransparentCanvas = function (canvas, r, g, b) {
    "use strict";

    var ctx, imageData, length, offset, data;

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    data = imageData.data;
    length = data.length;

    for (offset = 0; offset < length; offset += 4) {
        data[offset + 3] = data[offset];
        data[offset] = r;
        data[offset + 1] = g;
        data[offset + 2] = b;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
};
```

Case 1 still works as expected if the canvas size is changed from 400x200 to 400x350 (which made Case 3 break). Also, in Case 3 the transparent and red canvas *looks* correct.

Has anyone run into similar problems like this before? I would really like to know which Android versions have this behaviour, and if anyone's got some clever ideas how to circumvent this bug.

Comment: No problems here on Chrome and Android 4.3... ;)

Comment: No, I have not seen it in Chrome on 4.1 either. Seems to only occur in the preinstalled browser.

Comment: well, that's hell of a bug, I have the same problem, just a little difference, I am not facing in web browser instead in whole app itself.